# Node.js on Heroku: use middleware on development, but static assets on production?

Tags: node.js, deployment, heroku, assets

Some middle languages, such as `Stylus`, provides two ways to be compiled: through `connect` middleware or through CLI tool. The later can generate static compiled assets(i.e. `.css` files).

So I want to use middleware on development mode but static assets on production. I know that I can use `app.configure('developmen'...)` to ask `express` (not) to use some middlewares on development mode.

On an IaaS enviroment, like Amazon EC2, I can run a simple shell script to automatically re-compile all my assets. But how about PaaS, specifically Heroku? How can I tell it where my `.styl` are and where the `.css` should be generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take a look at https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets . It caches any built javascript or css files (it has stylus built-in support for stylus) if you pass it `build:true` .

You can ignore snockets (sprockets-like javascript include system) if you're not interested, although I enjoy using it. `#= require_tree app` and you include all the js files in that directory. And in development, you get separate script includes for easy debugging.

The biggest downside of serving directly with connect-assets on Heroku is that you need to git push to Heroku for every update to client code, which automatically triggers a restart. I ended up manually building my assets (with stylus and snockets), then uploading to S3. If you don't need to update the client code often, it's not that big of a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [express-cdn](https://github.com/niftylettuce/express-cdn), which will upload your assets to S3 on server start.

What I ended up doing was signing up at CloudFlare, and found that it wasn't as fast as using CloudFront, but it was very easy to setup and it works better than serving asset files from my dyno.